# telnet client - output hexadecimal network traffic on debian

Tags: debian, telnet

Reading the manpage I thought it should be possible to print incoming characters in hexadecimal. But it didn't work. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

This is the relevant manpage description:

```
debug           enable Debugging
netdata         enable printing of hexadecimal network data (debugging)
prettydump      enable output of "netdata" to user readable format (debugging)
options         enable viewing of options processing (debugging)
termdata        enable (debugging) toggle printing of hexadecimal terminal data
```

And this is the telnet session, as you can see only ASCII characters are printed:

```
telnet> set netdata
Will print hexadecimal representation of network traffic.
telnet> set termdata
Will print hexadecimal representation of terminal traffic.
telnet> set debug
Will turn on socket level debugging.
telnet> open 192.168.128.121 4015
Trying 192.168.128.121...
Connected to 192.168.128.121.
Escape character is '^]'.
?@?±?@?¦?@?¦?@?±?@?¦?@?±?@?¦^]
```

Answer (score 6):

This works as expected on a CentOS system I have to hand

```
telnet> set termdata
Will print hexadecimal representation of terminal traffic.
telnet> open localhost 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
> 0x0   5353482d322e302d4f70656e5353485f352e330a
```

and on an Ubuntu system I get the same results as you.

```
set termdata
Will print hexadecimal representation of terminal traffic.
telnet> open localhost 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
```

This could be a bug.

Answer (score 5):

Iain is right, tracing is buggy. See README.telnet in the ubuntu package 'telnet'.

However a simple workaround is to uninstall 'telnet' and install 'inetutils-telnet' which works as expected